# Return Southern or Northern won contracts on SUMIF with SUBTOTAL

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have done a SUMIF formula that returns all contracts that have been won for North and South (marked as 1 if won), but I want it to return only the Southern or Northern won contracts when I filter. I suppose I need a SUBTOTAL formula, but this doesn't work with a SUMIF Formula.

MY work sheet is set out as so

F = Area 
G = Value 
K = Won - identified by a 1 if won

The SUMIF Formula is =SUMIF(K9:K65,"1",G9:G65) which returns all southern and northern won contracts even upon filter. Can I add a subtotal formula to this make it return only the filter region?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your version of Excel is 2007 or later, you can use the SUMIFS function instead of SUMIF. SUMIFS allows you to check several different criteria.

In the following example, your original formula is in cell G6, cells G4 and G5 count the value of contracts won by the Northern and Southern regions. If there are other regions, you can filter any region by entering the region name in either F4 or F5.

The formula in G4 is

```
=SUMIFS($G$9:$G$65,$F$9:$F$65,F4,$K$9:$K$65,1)
```

You can copy that formula to G5.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you two simple formula.

First is Sumifs and other one is Sumproduct.

Check the Screen Shot below.

[image]

**Formulas are:**

```
=SUMIFS($B$55:$B$64,$A$55:$A$64,E55,$C$55:$C$64,1)

=SUMPRODUCT(($A$55:$A$64=E55)*($C$55:$C$64=1)*($B$55:$B$64))
```

**NB:** Adjust the Data Range as your need.